# how do i make a line in a python executable in terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#! /bin/python3

#Imports
import sys
import datetime

#Basic usage

print()

print()

print('Hello User. Welcome to ProjGURU, an innovative but basic project made by Unfree\'s CEO, Gururam. The current date and time is {}. Let\'s get right into the project.'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))

print()

lay1 = input('Please choose which programme to download and load.\n1.Tor\n2.Opera\n3.Chrome')
print()

#lay1 splitted

if lay1 == '1':wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

how do i execute the wget command

Comment: use subprocess() or os.system() command. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22676/2745495)

Comment: Use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

If your primary intention is to download that file, you can use the `requests` library, as Bruno pointed out in the comments. Install it via the command-line tool `pip`:

```
$ pip install requests
```

Then you can `import` the library and download your file as such:

```
import requests

# ... other code

if lay1 == '1':
    with open('google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb', 'wb') as f:
        r = requests.get('https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb')
        f.write(r.content)
```